# Switching Views Programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, tableview, viewcontroller

I have a few view controllers set up in IB.  One that has a TableView that has about 6 cells (populated programmatically).  And then 6 more view controllers (one for each cell).

I want to make it so that in my

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

I can make the view switch to whichever view is relative to the cell clicked.

So if they click cell1, it goes to view1, if they click cell2, it goes to view2.

This is how I init my table just btw and it works fine.

```
//tableview datasource delegate methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return showArray.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];


if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.showLabel.text = [showArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.seasonLabel.text = [seasonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 106;
}
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:    (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation{


NSIndexPath *newCellPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:showArray.count
                                              inSection:0];

[self.theatreView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newCellPath]
                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

Comment: How have you got your app structured. Is it sitting in a navigation controller?

Comment: @Bergasms No it has one View controller that is the main menu, and it just goes from controller to controller using UIButtons

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of these two methods based on how your app is structured.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];


[self presentModalViewController:newViewController animated:YES];

//for ios 6.0
[self presentViewController:newViewController animated:animated completion:NULL];
```

from what i can gather, you have a lot of uiviewcontrollers created in the .xib file of your main menu. is that correct? So you will have self.theatreViewController. You can then pass that as the parameter in the button callback. eg

```
[self presentViewController:self.theatreViewController animated:animated completion:NULL];
```

correct me if I am wrong in my assumptions here.

Comment: presentModalViewController:animated: deprecated in iOS 6 apparantly..  And also getting warning Incompatible pointer types sending 'TheatreViewController *_strong' to parameter of type 'UIViewController    What I wrote was [self presentModalViewController: TheatreViewController animated:YES];

Comment: you need to pass the actual variable to presentModalViewController. eg TheatreViewController *myviewController, you would pass myviewController in.   Also good catch with the ios6 deprecate, i forgot about that. Instead you use [self presentViewController:modalViewController animated:animated completion:NULL];

Comment: that would work (your edit to your answer) but theatreViewController is not a property of Viewcontroller so I can't use self.theatreViewController  But yes you are right I have many view controllers I just want to switch between them.  Edit: I get this error when clicking the button now. 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <ViewController: 0x7573de0>.

Comment: I think the issue here is that for some reason it sees the viewcontroller that I am adding as nil, and I'm not sure why

Comment: when you push a viewController check whether it is not nil and then push. if it is nil, alloc that viewController

Comment: @Bala how do i go about doing that (allocating it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of your app, but I think you may consider this:

```
- (UIViewController *)getViewControllerAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //..you can use "switch" to return the view controller you want
    return ...;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIViewController *controller = [self getViewControllerAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //..push or present your controller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **index path** property in this method:
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

like

yourObject = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath];

EDIT: - In your AppDelegate in the following method, do this:-

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{  

  self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

  mHomeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mHomeViewController];
  [mHomeViewController release];

  self.window.rootViewController = navController;
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [navController release];
  return YES;
}
```

Now, In your viewController - didSelectRowMethod, do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString * object = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if(newControllerInstance == nil) // check if it's nil, then initialize and alloc it.
   {
      newControllerInstance = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
      [self.navigationController newControllerInstance animated:YES];
      [newControllerInstance release];
   }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: I know how to find the index, if you read the below comments it seems that my view controller is Nil for some reason.  I don't know why though

Comment: If you just want to push the view, use [self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewController animated:YES]; , do you initialize and allocate your view controller?

Comment: I don't have a navigation controller, and what do you mean by initialze it and allocate it.  you mean do I have an -(id) init and stuff?

Comment: If you want to push to a view controller, you should have a navigaiton controller as the parent and you can use self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewController in order to push to a different view or you can use CATransitions (animations).

Comment: How would i initialize a nav controller @Angad

Comment: I already did that in the code, if you see in AppDelegate method.